# Iterating an array and replacing values

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to set this.arr.items to 1 when
this.inputObject.timeTable will return values from the map to me, e.g .:
I will give an example because it is difficult to explain it to me
For example:

```
  "timeTable":{
    "0": [{"from":"08:00","to":"12:00"}, {"from":"14:00","to":"16:00"}],
    "1": [{"from":"00:00","to":"05:00"}]
    "2": [],
    "3": []
    "4": [],
    "5": []
    "6": [] 
  }
```

i want to set this.arr.items:

```
 this.arr.items= [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  ];
```

My code:

```
  arr: Row[] = [
    { items: new Array(24).fill(1),active: true},
    { items: new Array(24).fill(1),active: true},
    { items: new Array(24).fill(1),active: true},
    { items: new Array(24).fill(1),active: true},
    { items: new Array(24).fill(1),active: true},
    { items: new Array(24).fill(1),active: true},
    { items: new Array(24).fill(1),active: true},
  ];


 if(this.inputObject.timeTable){
    for (let [key, value] of this.inputObject.timeTable.entries()) {
      this.arr.forEach(el=>{
        el.items.fill(0)
        el.active=false
      })
      value.forEach((el,ind)=>{
         for(let i = parseInt(el.from); i<parseInt(el.to)+1; i++){
          this.arr[key].items[i] = 1
        }
      })
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work
All my code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2lveus?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&fbclid=IwAR23d8PtUNJpMAOmqvFbe3PAQQhtNzydHSfSQv_UEsi7E3DKMPgv6PffXqg

Comment: Map return value ?/what does it mean ?

Comment: this.inputObject.timeTable is type Map

Comment: When do you want 1 as value for object ?

Comment: I do not know how to explain it, but the example shows, for example, from: "00:00", to: "02:00" then I want to set indexes 0 and 2 to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the hour part from `from` and `to` key for each object and then replace the value to 1 for every value in that range.

```js
const timeTables = { "0": [{"from":"08:00","to":"12:00"}, {"from":"14:00","to":"16:00"}], "1": [{"from":"00:00","to":"05:00"}], "2": [], "3": [], "4": [], "5": [], "6": [] },
    getHours = (time) => parseInt(time.split(':')[0], 10)
    result = Object.entries(timeTables).reduce((r, [key, value], i) => {
      r[i] = Array(24).fill(0);
      value.forEach(o => {
        let start = getHours(o.from);
        const end = getHours(o.to);
        while(start <= end) {
          r[i][start] = 1;
          start++;
        }
      })
      return r;
    }, []);
console.log(result.map(arr => arr.join(',')).join('\n'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: it doesn't work because:                                                       console.log(this.inputObject.timeTable)
console.log(Object.entries(this.inputObject.timeTable)) https://zapodaj.net/59ee6241fca7f.png.html

Comment: I don't understand, code is working in snippet. You need to check if `timeTable` object is an object.

Comment: timeTable is type Map

Comment: You can convert Map to object using `Object.fromEntries(map)`

Comment: ok, thanks. How can I replace this.arr.items with result?

Comment: Simply use `this.arr.items  = result`.

Comment: I have a message. "Property 'items' does not exist on type 'Row[]'."

Comment: I tried it but I don't know why it doesn't work this.arr.forEach(el=>el.items=result.map(e=>e))

Comment: Is your problem resolved now?

Answer (score 1):

Join time slot array based on `from` and `to` by `spread operator ...` or `Array.concat`.

```js
const config = {"timeTable":{
    "0": [{"from":"08:00","to":"12:00"}, {"from":"14:00","to":"16:00"}],
    "1": [{"from":"00:00","to":"05:00"}],
    "2": [],
    "3": [],
    "4": [],
    "5": [],
    "6": [] 
  }}
  
  function getTimeArray(timeTable) {
    const emptyArray = Array.from({length: 24}).map(() => 0)
    return Object.entries(timeTable).map(([key, value]) => {
      let result = emptyArray.slice()
      value.forEach((item) => {
        const beg = item.from.split(':')[0] * 1
        const to = item.to.split(':')[0] * 1
        result = [...result.slice(0, beg), ...result.slice(beg, to + 1).map(() => 1), ...result.slice(to + 1)]
      })
      return result
    })
  }
  console.log(
    JSON.stringify(getTimeArray(config.timeTable))
  )
```